# Allow a temporary filter view on protected sheets and ranges google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to allow temporary filter view on protected sheets and ranges in google sheets? Temporary filter view is allowed on view only mode. Any script file available.

Answer (score 2):

Wow,
I just found the question to my own answer. I wrote this script file to try it out and it worked.

```js
function Allowfilter(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    if (protection.sheet.FILTERVIEWMETHOD()) {
      protection.remove();
    }
  }
}
```